# Why doesn this JQuery resize work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a script to run only if the viewport is below 1025. Then on resize, if if the screen size is increased either ignore or run the script. At present it runs whatever screen size.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
     if ($(window).width() < 1025) {

         var $caseStudies = $('.case-study');
         $('.pagination div').on('click', function() {
            $caseStudies.css("position", "absolute"); 
            $caseStudies.eq($(this).index()).css("position", "relative"); 
         });

     }
    else {
        // ELEMENT IS ABSOLUTE
    }
   });
});
```

Comment: Your goal is unclear but you probably should start your resize callback by *unbinding* the click event handler. Because right now you either do nothing or add another event handler without removing the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in your code to remove the handler you set up in the `< 1025` case when the window is no longer `< 1025` in size. You have to explicitly remove the handler. Probably the easiest way is with an event class. You'll also need a marker to indicate whether the handler has been attached. See `***` comments:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hasHandler = false;
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 1025) {
            // *** Add handler if we don't already have it
            if (!hasHandler) {
                hasHandler = true;
                var $caseStudies = $('.case-study');
                $('.pagination div').on('click.positioner', function() {
                    // *** Note ------------------^^^^^^^^^^^
                    $caseStudies.css("position", "absolute");
                    $caseStudies.eq($(this).index()).css("position", "relative");
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            // If we ever added a handler...
            if (hasHandler) {
                hasHandler = false;
                // *** Remove it
                $('.pagination div').off('click.positioner');
                // *** Make them all relative again
                $('.case-study').css("position", "relative");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

In a comment you've said:

> ... this script only seems to work after I resize the browser. I would need it to work if the browser was less than 1025 but detect a resize, if resized

Then you'd simply put the code in a function and call that function *both* from `ready` (on page load) *and* in response to resize:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hasHandler = false;
    function handlePositioning() {
        if ($(window).width() < 1025) {
            // *** Add handler if we don't already have it
            if (!hasHandler) {
                hasHandler = true;
                var $caseStudies = $('.case-study');
                $('.pagination div').on('click.positioner', function() {
                    // *** Note ------------------^^^^^^^^^^^
                    $caseStudies.css("position", "absolute");
                    $caseStudies.eq($(this).index()).css("position", "relative");
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            // If we ever added a handler...
            if (hasHandler) {
                hasHandler = false;
                // *** Remove it
                $('.pagination div').off('click.positioner');
                // *** Make them all relative again
                $('.case-study').css("position", "relative");
            }
        }
    }
    handlePositioning();
    $(window).resize(handlePositioning);
});
```

(Or you can add `.trigger("resize")` at the end of the `.on` call in the first code block above to trigger the event after adding it, but that's always seemed hacky to me...)

Comment: You're adding another event handler without removing the previous one. A solution would be to start the resize callback by always remove it.

Comment: @DenysSéguret: OMG how did I ever manage to hit Post Answer with such a bonehead mistake!! Thank you. I'll fix it, but if you post in the meantime...

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however, this script only seems to work after I resize the browser. I would need it to work if the browser was less than 1025 but detect a resize, if resized.

Comment: @Al-76: You'd want to include that in the question. The solution is simple: Put the code doing the work in a function, and call that function within the `ready` handler *and* on resize.